# How to initialize an array of a List<Float>

Tags: arrays, arraylist, jmonkeyengine, nurbs

I am learning to build a surface using JMonkey api. The class `Surface` has a method

```
 createNurbsSurface(controlPoints, nurbKnots, uSegments, vSegments, basisUFunctionDegree, basisVFunctionDegree).
```

I am trying to make a simple example to understand the meaning of the arguments. However, I can't initialize the second argument:

```
List<Float>[] nurbKnots
```

I tried:

```
List<Float>[] nurbKnots = {new ArrayList<Float>()};
```

but it complains that you cannot create a generic array of `List<Float>.`

Could someone show me how to initialize this `nurbKnots.`

Comment: What is the type of `nurbKnots` ?

Comment: the type is List<Float>[]

Comment: Check the code, see if it works!!

Comment: It requires: Change type of 'nurbKnots' to 'List<Float>[]

Comment: If `createNurbsSurface()` defines its second parameter of type `List<Float>[]` then my code should work !!! Can you post the method declaration with argument type ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for non-generic `List`:

```
List[] listNonGeneric = new ArrayList[10];
```

But this won't work:

```
List<Float>[] listGeneric = new ArrayList<Float>[10];
```

You have to use:

```
List<List<Float>> nurbKnots = new ArrayList<>();
```

and pass the argument as

```
(List<Float>[])nurbKnots.toArray();
```

Comment: I could compile, however I caught the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.List;
 at br.unesp.lbbc.testes.TestaJMonkey.<init>(TestaJMonkey.java:51)
 at br.unesp.lbbc.testes.TestaJMonkey.main(TestaJMonkey.java:69)

Answer (score 0):

One friend helped. He told me:

> In Java, it's not really possible to have arrays of generic types (safely). You have to allow unchecked assignment. Something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Float>[] f = new List[2];
f[0] = new ArrayList<Float>();
f[0].add(0.1);
f[1] = new ArrayList<Float>();
f[1].add(0.2);
```

But, it worked!